# Ubuntu 14.04 Server With LAMP not Displaying Images Forbidden

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

I've got a digitalocean server running Ubuntu 14.04, with a LAMP stack, for a PHP powered site. The issue I'm having is that the site often won't display images, or at least will only display some. If you try and navigate directly to the image url, you get a 403 Forbidden. So far I've been just running sudo chown -$ www-data /var/www/html and that's been working. So each time I might completely delete and re-upload the site (for various reasons), some of the photos stop displaying, and I run the chown command, which fixes this. This also happens with images I'm uploading for the first time, such as a new favicon.

How can I get around this permanently, securely? So that any new image will not give a 403 error when a user views the site?

Comment: what are you using to upload?

Comment: It's probably that, you have a few choices here. The one that seem easier is to put www-data into your user group, then on the SFTP upload files with permission for group RW, like 664 for files and 775 for folders

Comment: Is there a better way to upload files?

Comment: None that will be easier. If you have your code hosted some where like github or bitbucket you could make a script that would fetch the changes. But its easy to do SFTP

Comment: Hmm, I do use bitbucket. So for now, just keep running chown? The other option you'd mentioned I didn't quite understand, to be honest.